# Disable ⌘+SHIFT+F keyboard shortcut for fullscren

Tags: macos, keyboard

I use [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) to allow me to hit <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to maximize a window.  However, sometimes I miss the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key, and this results in the system shortcut for moving the window to a new space to happen instead.

Trying to set <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> as the key combination in Spectacle produces a "this is a system shortcut, please disable it in system preferences" message, but I can't find that shortcut anywhere under keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences.

How can I disable <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>?

This is OSX Yosemite.

Comment: That shortcut is under the Finder's Go menu, and it's used to open a new Finder window to display All My Files.

Comment: That shortcut is used in multiple places. It would be wiser to change it in Spectacle app.

Answer (score 1):

BetterTouchTool. Create a custom shortcut with CMD+SHIFT+F under Golbal, and leave the Assigned Action to blank. BTT will override the built-in action.